# Decrement value instead of setting it like `number = number - 1`. Is it possible in Magento?

Tags: model, sql, resource-model

I need to decrement a value *with an atomic database operation*, is it possible using Magento models?

`setNumber($number)` works like `number = $number`, but I need it to be decremented in SQL query.

Is it possible in Magento or do I have to write the SQL query myself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about MYSQL

Comment: @Sander-MageStackDay2015 It's not about MYSQL, I am asking if there is a Magento function that instead of `setNumber(number)` has something like `decreaseBy(number)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using `Zend_Db_Expr`:

```
$object->setNumber(new Zend_Db_Expr('number-1'));
```

### For reference:

The method `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForSave()` contains the following code:

```
if ($object->hasData($field)) {
    $fieldValue = $object->getData($field);
    if ($fieldValue instanceof Zend_Db_Expr) {
        $data[$field] = $fieldValue;
    } else {
        ... [normal value processing follows]
```

### EAV Models:

Note that you only can reference the attribute by its name ("number" in the example) if it's a real column of the main table, not an EAV attribute.

Although the abovementioned method is only used by models with flat tables, `Zend_Db_Expr` can be used for EAV attributes as well, the method that handles it is `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::prepareColumnValue()`.

**BUT** you always have use the column name "`value`":

```
$product->setNumber(new Zend_Db_Expr('value-1'));
```

You don't need to specify a table alias because during save each attribute gets processed with its own query, so "value" is not ambiguous.

Comment: /me sheds a tear...

Comment: They are tears of joy. Great answer.

Comment: And how does one do this with a collection? :)

Comment: There is no direct way to save attributes in a collection at once but you probably can do some clever stuff with `$collection->getSelect()`

Answer (score 0):

```
try ->setNumber(getNumber() - $number)
```

Edit: This would be equivalent of `Set number = number - X` in mysql where X is $number.

If you want to do it in MySQL only then you just need to write a query.

Comment: this will be `number=some_number` in sql query

Comment: write a sample query you want or an example...you aren't clear enough.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET number = number - 1`

Comment: See my updated answer.....

Comment: your example would product `UPDATE table SET number = 5`

Comment: I mean ->setNumber(getNumber() - $number) AND UPDATE table SET number = number - 1  would have the same result if $number value is 1.

Comment: Technically, it's not because you can get race conditions.

Comment: The question is asking for an *atomic database operation* - which your solution is not.

Comment: The question was edited to include atomic database operation after my answer :)