# How do I lock a row after using load()?

Tags: database

Let's say I do the following:

```
$favorite = Mage::getModel('testing/favorites')->load(4);
.....
$favorite->save();
```

How do I make sure the row 4 has been locked and can't be accessed until I call save()?

Edit:

Essentially, I have one table with a column (not id column, not autoincrement) that is a counter, which increments every time a call is made to a function. If two people access this row concurrently, how can I make sure the value is +2 at the end, and not +1?

For example:
User A and B call

> incrementAction(4);

If the row 4 has a favorite_count = 500, it should, by the end, have a value of 502. The +1 from user A, and the +1 from user B, rather than each incrementing 500 for each +1  and ending up with 501 when each of them calls save().

Comment: don't use the $favorite variable until when you save

Comment: Your updated question is answered here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57470/decrement-value-instead-of-setting-it-like-number-number-1-is-it-possible/57476#57476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your updated question is answered here: [Decrement value instead of setting it like `number = number - 1`. Is it possible in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57470/decrement-value-instead-of-setting-it-like-number-number-1-is-it-possible/57476#57476) (in short: use `$object->setFoo(new Zend_Db_Expr('foo+4'));` to increment `foo` by 4)

To answer the original question for future reference: You could use a transaction like this:

```
$model->getResource()->beginTransaction();
$model->load($id);
// do stuff...
$model->save();
$model->getResource()->commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Alright I read the question you linked me to. So, does doing $favorites->setFavoritesCount(new Zend_Db_Expr('favorites_count-1'));  do the same thing you did in your answer? As in, is it atomic/safe to use? Or do I need to use a transaction AND use Zend_Db_Expr?

Comment: No need for a transaction then. It will use a query like `SET favorites_count=favorites_count-1` for saving the object.

Answer (score 2):

Magento will do the lock for you when necessary. If you really want to control this yourself then you could write your own queries and use: LOCK IN SHARE MODE within a transaction, after you commit the lock will be released.

For eg:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM t WHERE i = 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

For more info check here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Comment: Currently what I'm doing, I'm accessing a row, incrementing an INT value, and saving it. Will it lock for that? If two people access the same function to increment, I don't want to end up incrementing only once since they'll both increment, for example 500 to 501, and then they'll both save  501 instead of 502.

Comment: I see, can you then reformulate the question. I think the answer I gave you covers your original question. Let me see If I understand correctly what you need: you have one table with a column (not id column, not autoincrement) that is some sort of counter and you want to add +1, if two people access this row concurrently then the value should be +2 at the end?

Comment: Indeed, that's correct.