# How to increment a column based on another column (max value) in a different table in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, model

I need to update a column based on another column (max value) in a different table in Magento. If the updated value is not greater than the max value then update other wise not. 
By Updating I meant it includes a arithemetic operation, eg Increment.

How to do it in Magento Way instead of writing a Mysql query ?

Comment: For updating with an arithmetic operation, see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57470/decrement-value-instead-of-setting-it-like-number-number-1-is-it-possible/57476#57476

Answer (score 1):

it's probably the easiest to add this to the `_prepareDataForSave` method in your resource model. The `Log` module has a nice example of that in `Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor`

So, if you do something like

```
$model = Mage::getModel('[namespace]_[module]/mycustommodel')->setData([
   'foo' => 'bar'
])->save();
```

and add the method to the right resource model it would look something like

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Resource_Mycustommodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Prepare data for save
     *
     * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $data
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _prepareDataForSave($data)
    {
        return array(
            'foo' => $data->getBar(),
            'increment_thingy' => '[your custom value]'
        );
    }
}
```